# Prove that term of upper central series of a group $G$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $Z(G$) be the center of G. The upper central series
$1=Z_0(G)≤Z_1(G)≤…,$ is defined by $Z_{n+1}(G)/Z_n(G)=Z(G/Z_n(G))$.

Let $Z_n(G)$ be $n^{th}$ term of the upper central serie of a group $G$.

> Prove that $Z_n(G)$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G.$

I use the math induction.
It is easy to prove that $Z_0(G)$ or $Z_1(G)$ a characteristic subgroup of $G.$ Assume that $Z_i(G) (i=0\ldots n-1)$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G.$ I can't deduce that $Z_i(G)$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G.$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\alpha \in {\rm Aut}(G)$. By inductive hypothesis, $\alpha(Z_{n-1}(G)) = Z_{n-1}(G)$. So $\alpha$ induces an automorphism $\overline{\alpha}$ of $G/Z_{n-1}(G)$ defined by $\overline{\alpha}(gZ_{n-1}(G)) = \alpha(g)Z_{n-1}(G)$.

Since $Z(G/Z_{n-1}(G))$ is characteristic in $G/Z_{n-1}(G)$, $\overline{\alpha}$ fixes $Z(G/Z_{n-1}(G))$. But, by definition, $Z(G/Z_{n-1}(G)) = Z_n(G)/Z_{n-1}(G)$ so, for any $g \in Z_n(G)$, $\overline{\alpha}(gZ_{n-1}(G)) = \alpha(g)Z_{n-1}(G)\in Z_n(G)/Z_{n-1}(G)$, and hence $\alpha(g) \in Z_n(G)$.

We have proved that $\alpha(Z_n(G)) \le Z_n(G)$ Similarly $\alpha^{-1}(Z_n(G)) \le Z_n(G)$ and applying $\alpha$ to this gives $Z_n(G)) \le \alpha(Z_n(G))$. Hence $Z_n(G)$ is characteristic in $G$.

Comment: I don't understand why $Z(G/Z_{n-1}(G))$ is characteristic. Do You mean  $\alpha(g Z_{n-1}(G)) \in Z_n(G)/Z_{n-1}(G)$ instead of $\alpha(g) Z_{n-1}(G)) \in Z_n(G)/Z_{n-1}(G)?$

Comment: No I meant what I wrote! But I have added more detail. For any group $G$, $Z(G)$ is characteristic in $G$. You are probably expected to know that already.

Answer (score 0):

$Z_1(G)$ is of course characteristic.Now let(induction) $\phi(Z_{n-1})\leq Z_{n-1}$ for some $\phi\in Aut(G)$. Want to show $\phi(Z_n)\leq Z_n$.Let $t\in Z_n$ then $[t,G]\in Z_{n-1}$, therefore $[\phi(t),G]\in \phi(Z_{n-1})\leq Z_{n-1}$.So $\phi(t)\in Z_n$.